# Python AVL Tree

Tags: python, beginner, algorithm, python-3.x, tree

I decided to implement some data structures- this time an AVL tree. I think the logic is correct. Is there a way to make it clearer and do you have any ideas about more tests to add?

```
# An AVL tree, python
import random


class TreeNode:
    def __init__(self, key, val, left=None, right=None, parent=None, bal=0):
        self.key = key
        self.payload = val
        self.leftChild = left
        self.rightChild = right
        self.parent = parent
        self.balanceFactor = bal

    def update_val(self, new_val):  # added
        self.payload = new_val

    def hasLeftChild(self):
        return self.leftChild

    def hasRightChild(self):
        return self.rightChild

    def isLeftChild(self):
        return self.parent and self.parent.leftChild == self

    def isRightChild(self):
        return self.parent and self.parent.rightChild == self

    def isRoot(self):
        return not self.parent

    def isLeaf(self):
        return not (self.rightChild or self.leftChild)

    def hasAnyChildren(self):
        return self.rightChild or self.leftChild

    def hasBothChildren(self):
        return self.rightChild and self.leftChild

    def replaceNodeData(self, key, value, lc, rc):
        self.key = key
        self.payload = value
        self.leftChild = lc
        self.rightChild = rc
        if self.hasLeftChild():
            self.leftChild.parent = self
        if self.hasRightChild():
            self.rightChild.parent = self

    def findSuccessor(self):
        succ = None
        if self.hasRightChild():
            succ = self.rightChild.findMin()
        else:
            if self.parent:
                if self.isLeftChild():
                    succ = self.parent
                else:
                    self.parent.rightChild = None
                    succ = self.parent.findSuccessor()
                    self.parent.rightChild = self
        return succ

    def findMin(self):
        current = self
        while current.hasLeftChild():
            current = current.leftChild
        return current

    def spliceOut(self):
        if self.isLeaf():
            if self.isLeftChild():
                self.parent.leftChild = None
            else:
                self.parent.rightChild = None
        elif self.hasAnyChildren():
            if self.hasLeftChild():
                if self.isLeftChild():
                    self.parent.leftChild = self.leftChild
                else:
                    self.parent.rightChild = self.leftChild
                self.leftChild.parent = self.parent
            else:
                if self.isLeftChild():
                    self.parent.leftChild = self.rightChild
                else:
                    self.parent.rightChild = self.rightChild
                self.rightChild.parent = self.parent


class BinarySearchTree:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None
        self.size = 0

    def length(self):
        return self.size

    def __len__(self):
        return self.size

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.get(key)

    def __setitem__(self, k, v):
        self.put(k, v)

    def put(self, key, val):
        if self.root:
            self._put(key, val, self.root)
        else:
            self.root = TreeNode(key, val)
        self.size = self.size + 1

    def _put(self, key, val, currentNode):
       if key == currentNode.key:
            currentNode.update_val(val)
            return
        if key < currentNode.key:
            if currentNode.hasLeftChild():
                self._put(key, val, currentNode.leftChild)
            else:
                currentNode.leftChild = TreeNode(key, val,       parent=currentNode)
                self.updateBalance(currentNode.leftChild)
        else:
            if currentNode.hasRightChild():
                self._put(key, val, currentNode.rightChild)
            else:
                currentNode.rightChild = TreeNode(key, val, parent=currentNode)
                self.updateBalance(currentNode.rightChild)

    def rotateLeft(self, rotRoot):
        newRoot = rotRoot.rightChild
        rotRoot.rightChild = newRoot.leftChild
        if newRoot.leftChild != None:
            newRoot.leftChild.parent = rotRoot
        newRoot.parent = rotRoot.parent
        if rotRoot.isRoot():
            self.root = newRoot
        else:
            if rotRoot.isLeftChild():
                rotRoot.parent.leftChild = newRoot
            else:
                rotRoot.parent.rightChild = newRoot
        newRoot.leftChild = rotRoot
        rotRoot.parent = newRoot
        rotRoot.balanceFactor = rotRoot.balanceFactor + 1 -  min(newRoot.balanceFactor, 0)
        newRoot.balanceFactor = newRoot.balanceFactor + 1 + max(rotRoot.balanceFactor, 0)

    def rotateRight(self, rotRoot):
        newRoot = rotRoot.leftChild
        rotRoot.leftChild = newRoot.rightChild
        if newRoot.rightChild != None:
            newRoot.rightChild.parent = rotRoot
        newRoot.parent = rotRoot.parent
        if rotRoot.isRoot():
            self.root = newRoot
        else:
            if rotRoot.isLeftChild():
                rotRoot.parent.leftChild = newRoot
            else:
                rotRoot.parent.rightChild = newRoot
        newRoot.rightChild = rotRoot
        rotRoot.parent = newRoot
        rotRoot.balanceFactor = rotRoot.balanceFactor - 1 -    max(newRoot.balanceFactor, 0)
        newRoot.balanceFactor = newRoot.balanceFactor - 1 + min(0, rotRoot.balanceFactor)

    def updateBalance(self, node):
        if node.balanceFactor > 1 or node.balanceFactor < -1:
            self.rebalance(node)
            return
        if node.parent != None:
            if node.isLeftChild():
                node.parent.balanceFactor += 1
            elif node.isRightChild():
                node.parent.balanceFactor -= 1

            if node.parent.balanceFactor != 0:
                self.updateBalance(node.parent)


    def rebalance(self, node):
        if node.balanceFactor < 0:
            if node.rightChild.balanceFactor > 0:
                self.rotateRight(node.rightChild)
                self.rotateLeft(node)
            else:
                self.rotateLeft(node)
        elif node.balanceFactor > 0:
            if node.leftChild.balanceFactor < 0:
                self.rotateLeft(node.leftChild)
                self.rotateRight(node)
            else:
                self.rotateRight(node)

    def get(self, key):
        if self.root:
            res = self._get(key, self.root)
            if res:
                return res.payload
            else:
                return None
        else:
            return None

    def _get(self, key, currentNode):
        if not currentNode:
            return None
        elif currentNode.key == key:
            return currentNode
        elif key < currentNode.key:
            return self._get(key, currentNode.leftChild)
        else:
            return self._get(key, currentNode.rightChild)

    def __delitem__(self, key):
        self.delete(key)

    def delete(self, key):
         if self.size > 1:
             nodeToRemove = self._get(key, self.root)
             if nodeToRemove:
                 self.remove(nodeToRemove)
                 self.size = self.size - 1
             else:
                 raise KeyError('Error, key not in tree')
         elif self.size == 1 and self.root.key == key:
             self.root = None
             self.size = self.size - 1
         else:
             raise KeyError('Error, key not in tree')

    def remove(self, currentNode):
        if currentNode.isLeaf():  # this is leaf
            if currentNode == currentNode.parent.leftChild:
                currentNode.parent.leftChild = None
                currentNode.parent.balanceFactor -= 1
                if currentNode.parent.balanceFactor < -1:
                    self.updateBalance(currentNode.parent)
            else:
                currentNode.parent.rightChild = None
                currentNode.parent.balanceFactor += 1
                if currentNode.parent.balanceFactor > 1:
                    self.updateBalance(currentNode.parent)
        elif currentNode.hasBothChildren():  # this is interior node
            succ = currentNode.findSuccessor()
            succ.spliceOut()
            if succ.isLeftChild():
                succ.parent.balanceFactor -= 1
                self.updateBalance(succ.parent)
            elif succ.isRightChild():
                succ.parent.balanceFactor += 1
                self.updateBalance(succ.parent)
            currentNode.key = succ.key
            currentNode.payload = succ.payload

        else:  # this node has one child
            if currentNode.hasLeftChild():
                if currentNode.isLeftChild():
                    currentNode.leftChild.parent = currentNode.parent
                    currentNode.parent.leftChild = currentNode.leftChild
                    currentNode.parent.balanceFactor -= 1
                    self.updateBalance(currentNode.parent)
                elif currentNode.isRightChild():
                    currentNode.leftChild.parent = currentNode.parent
                    currentNode.parent.rightChild = currentNode.leftChild
                    currentNode.parent.balanceFactor += 1
                    self.updateBalance(currentNode.parent)
                else:
                    currentNode.replaceNodeData(currentNode.leftChild.key,
                                            currentNode.leftChild.payload,
                                             currentNode.leftChild.leftChild,
                                              currentNode.leftChild.rightChild)
            else:
                if currentNode.isLeftChild():
                    currentNode.rightChild.parent = currentNode.parent
                    currentNode.parent.leftChild = currentNode.rightChild
                    currentNode.parent.balanceFactor -= 1
                    self.updateBalance(currentNode.parent)
                elif currentNode.isRightChild():
                    currentNode.rightChild.parent = currentNode.parent
                    currentNode.parent.rightChild = currentNode.rightChild
                    currentNode.parent.balanceFactor += 1
                    self.updateBalance(currentNode.parent)
                else:
                      currentNode.replaceNodeData(currentNode.rightChild.key,
                                            currentNode.rightChild.payload,
                                            currentNode.rightChild.leftChild,
                                            currentNode.rightChild.rightChild)


# End of the Tree



# Tests helping methods
def height_node(tree_node):
    if not tree_node:
        return 0
    else:
        return 1 + max(height_node(tree_node.leftChild), height_node(tree_node.rightChild))


def is_balanced(tree_node):
    return abs(height_node(tree_node.leftChild) -     height_node(tree_node.rightChild)) <= 1


def list_print(tree_node):
    def top_height(tree_node):
        if not tree_node:
            return 0
        else:
            return 1 + top_height(tree_node.parent)
    if not tree_node:
        return []
    else:
        size = height_node(tree_node.root)
        l1 = [[] for x in range(size)]
        def travel_list(current):
            if current:
                travel_list(current.leftChild)
                l1[top_height(current) - 1].append(current.key)
                travel_list(current.rightChild)
            return l1

        l = travel_list(tree_node.root)
        for x in range(len(l)):
            print(l[x])

# tests in a loop:
for f in range(100):
    mytree1 = BinarySearchTree()
    for x in range(1000):
        mytree1.put(random.randint(-10000, 10000), "a")
    for i in range(100):
        if mytree1.get(i):
            mytree1.delete(i)
        if not is_balanced(mytree1.root):
            print("not good")
            h = height_node(mytree1.root)
            print("height: ", h)
            list_print(mytree1)
            break
    del (mytree1)

print("OK")
```

It's based on this page: [Balanced Binary Search Trees](http://interactivepython.org/runestone/static/pythonds/Trees/BalancedBinarySearchTrees.html)

Comment: I'm missing [documentation strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id32). Replacing the key (/children) of a node should come with warnings - or checks (/restoration(s)) of order. The interface looks fat. I'd expect `findMin` with BST rather than node, and `findMax` and `findPredecessor` to be at least mentioned as being left out for being just symmetrical.

Comment: Thanks for remarks, will work on it. Yes, it is fat, but all these things need to be there. My thoughts about findMin, findPredecessor and findMin are the same, but the way how function remove receives it's argument (the argument type is Node)  makes this design easier to implement.

Comment: Seeing the amount of code identical to the [hyperlinked base](https://runestone.academy/runestone/books/published/pythonds/Trees/SearchTreeImplementation.html), I won't post a review I put hours in (for my own benefit - tinkering with "rank balanced trees", factoring out symmetries in Python binary tree implementations).

Answer (score 1):

In terms of testing, delete has some additional cases that should be tested.  Knuth's "Art of Computer Programming" Vol. 3 has a lot of great information regarding AVL trees and that is why in my tests I implemented a delete from a Fibonacci Tree.  You can see some tests in Java [here](https://github.com/dmcmanam/bbst-showdown/blob/master/src/main/test/bbst_showdown/AVLTreeMapTest.java), they should translate easily to Python.

For simplicity, you might consider changing to storing height/rank instead of balance factor.  The [bottom-up rebalancing for insertion is very easy to understand](https://refactoringlightly.wordpress.com/2017/11/05/rank-balanced-avl-trees-on-github/) if you have read about rank balanced trees.